# Maximum protection on a computer network?

Tags: network, firewalls, backup

I would like to secure as much as possible a computer I am using to sync sensitive data files from work to my home pc. The syncronisation is being done by only 1 software is there a firewall to allow connections to the internet only by that 1 software (and windows updates also) and NOWHERE else so an attacker cant find a weakhole in the home pc?

Also please, what recommendations would you give me so that the home pc is more secure?
 Are there any tools to block all incoming connections to my pc except from that software and any other security measures I would take? I am very stressed i dont want to loose my job over this thing.
 What other tools are there for a computer to use when its only for backup and needs maximum security?

Some info about the home pc: it is a desktop used only for the backup purposes and nothing more.
 I dont even surf the web from it. So no chance of me downloading something (virus etc).

Comment: I know you're not looking to hear this but the notion of absolute security is a myth. I would rather avoid making recommendations that may not provide sufficient "security" should data be lost. With that said, I would follow any agreement you have with your employer and let the employer provide an approved method/device for access to data. Dataloss is more common and anyone, even a security practitioner, could be a victim [datalossdb](http://datalossdb.org/).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, even though I know its never possible to become absolutely secured. The tighter security I will have the best. Any software or any important tips I should look into?

Comment: Actually, there **is** such a thing as absolute security, though it's not easy, cheap or practical. First, unplug the machine. Second, acquire a rocket. Third, attach the computer to said rocket. Fourth, fire the rocket into the sun.

Comment: The fact you are asking this question means your home pc is not setup in the way you think it is.  It seems like you syncing senistive files in the way you are doing so, is not actually all that secure, your home pc is not protected in the same way as your work pc.  Furthermore your employer cannot protect you ony our home pc, which means if you leak the date, it will be entirely YOUR fault.

Answer (score 5):

**Pragmatic advice.** The best advice I can give you is not technical advice; it is organizational.  You don't want to lose your jobs.  That's understandable.  The best way to meet that goal is, Don't try to do this yourself.

Your company almost certainly has an IT department.  Contact them to ask them how they'd like you to secure your home PC and what practices they want you to follow them.   Then, do what they say.  If you follow their guidelines, then even if something bad should happen, you should have good protection against being fired.  Hopefully few companies would fire a valuable employee who acted in good faith and followed the rules faithfully.

**Technical methods for hardening.**  If you want technical advice, you can find all sorts of advice on how to harden a Windows PC.  Here's my top list:

- Enable Windows automatic updates.
- Get anti-virus software and enable it.
- Turn on a firewall to block all incoming connections, except for the sync software.  A google search on Windows Firewall should provide directions on how to do so.
- Take regular backups.
- Follow the advice listed in this question: [If you have to write an information security guide for non technical users, what would you cover?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/11861/971)
- Install Secunia PSI and set it to scan your computer for unpatched software periodically.  Follow its advice to update any old software it finds.
- If you want to be extra-cautious, you could follow the advice here: [Quick steps to Windows 7 OS hardening](http://www.winfrastructure.net/article.aspx?BlogEntry=Quick-steps-to-Windows-7-OS-hardening).

If you follow the steps listed above, you should be among the top 5% of security practice, perhaps the top 1%.